# How to integrate Paypal Direct Payment (i.e. Paypal Pro) with custom shopping cart application?

Tags: web-development, website-design, security, paypal, payments

I've written a basic shopping cart application that is fully functional *except* for the payment process. I have decided to use PayPal Direct Payment, or "PayPal Pro," but am unsure of how to integrate it with my website. Does anyone know of any tutorials or resources that explain step by step how to integrate PayPal with a website?

As a side note, just so that no one feels obligated to state this, I know that it's important that this be "done right," as one can get in big trouble if customer information is not kept secure. I fully intend on having a professional review my entire application and help me be PCI complaint, but I want to do as much as the work myself as I possibly can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Payflow Pro integration documentation is available [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools) and there are some quick start guides [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides).  I've implemented this myself (about 4+ years ago) and it was really straightforward.  I spent more time verifying that the product I was developing was PCI compliant, etc, than I did actually plugging this mechanism in.